# Error creating Geospatial index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection ('stops') with 14000 records imported from a CSV. Included in each record is some geospatial data, which I've converted into an array, so each essentially looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  // other fields
  "loc": [
    153.019073,
    -27.467834
  ]
}
```

When I run `db.stops.ensureIndex({ loc: '2d' })` it gives the error:

> location object expected, location array not in correct format

I guess that something's wrong in one of the fields, but I can't figure out which one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was a single record which wasn't imported correctly (probably an empty line at the end of the file).

To find it (and later remove it), I used the [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where) operator:

```
db.stops.find({ $where: 'typeof this.loc[0] != "number"' })
```